# Cross origin blocked between Ajax and Spring Controller

Tags: ajax, spring, spring-mvc, cors

I want a Javascript function to send data to a Spring controller and get a response. However, due to the strict-origin-when-cross-origin Referrer policy, the request does not go through.

Spring Controller :

```
@Controller
public class EventController {

@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value = "/event", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String handleAjax(@RequestParam Integer id, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {

    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

    return "OK";

}
}
```

Javascript functions :

```
function getContextPath() {
return window.location.pathname.substring(0, window.location.pathname.indexOf("/",2));
}  

function move(moveDir,velocity){
$.ajax({
    type : "POST",
    url : getContextPath()  + "/event",
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data)
    }
});
}
```

I know that I have to allow cross-origin for these files. So far, the things I tried didn't work.
List of what I tried :

-> Adding `@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:8081", maxAge = 3600)` to the controller

-> Adding `response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");` to the controller

-> Adding `crossorigin="anonymous"` to the Javascript `<script>` tag

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I finally got it. There were two problems.

The first was that I had to add that **header** to the **ajax** request, to allow the request to be handled by the server: `headers: {  'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '/path_to_request_target' },`. Putting `'*'` instead of `'/path_to_request_target'` would also work.

The second was with my **dispatcher servlet**. I had to put `.html` at the end of the URL : `url : getContextPath()  + "/event.html",`. This is due of the mapping of my dispatcher servlet :

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/index.jsp</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Adding `.html` to the URL worked because of `<url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>`. Adding a `<url-pattern>` that satisfied the format of the inital URL would also work.

Answer (score 0):

Your code won't work because you specify to support POST method only

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/event", method = RequestMethod.POST)
```

OPTIONS method is required as Preflighted requests in CORS.

So you must support POST and OPTIONS also to make it work.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/event")
@RequestMapping(value = "/event", method = { RequestMethod.POST, RequestMethod.OPTIONS })
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/OPTIONS